# how to use sum function with were condition and isnull check in linq to entity?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, linq-to-entities

happy new year... i am working with linq to entity, and got struck here,

```
SELECT O.InvoiceId, O.CustID, O.PickupDate, O.OrderDate, O.OrderNumber, O.ProNumber, O.PO1, O.PO2,
O.BaseRATE,O.OrderTotal,O.DiscAmount,
O.NormalDiscount,
ISNULL((Select Sum(AccessorialChargeAmount) from OrderDriverExtraCharge where OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber),0) As AccCharge,
ISNULL((SELECT Sum(AccessorialChargeAmount) FROM AccessorialCharge INNER JOIN
OrderDriverExtraCharge ON AccessorialCharge.AccessorialChargeId = OrderDriverExtraCharge.AccessorialChargeId
WHERE (((AccessorialCharge.Taxable)=1) AND ((OrderDriverExtraCharge.OrderNumberId)=O.OrderNumberId))),0) As Taxable FROM [Order] O
WHERE (((O.InvoiceId)=@InvoiceId))
Order By OrderNumberId
```

this is a huge sql qry i have to conver it in linq to entity query.

i am doing like

```
 var qry = (from O in _uow.Orders.GetAll()
join OD in _uow.OrderDriverExtraCharge.GetAll() on O.OrderNumberId equals OD.OrderNumberId
let AC in _uow.AccessorialCharges.GetAll() on OD.AccessorialChargeId equals AC.AccessorialChargeId
where O.InvoiceId == InvoiceId
select new {

});
```

but don't know how to use sum function with where condition, and is null :(

specially i am getting confused with this part

```
ISNULL((SELECT Sum(AccessorialChargeAmount) FROM AccessorialCharge INNER JOIN
    OrderDriverExtraCharge ON AccessorialCharge.AccessorialChargeId = OrderDriverExtraCharge.AccessorialChargeId
    WHERE (((AccessorialCharge.Taxable)=1) AND ((OrderDriverExtraCharge.OrderNumberId)=O.OrderNumberId))),0) As Taxable FROM [Order] O
    WHERE (((O.InvoiceId)=@InvoiceId))
    Order By OrderNumberId
```

don't know how to use is null with where and some conditions.

any suggestion or any related example  will be appreciated. i will mark your answer if it works for me. thanks in advance. happy new year.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this

```
from O in _uow.Orders.GetAll()
where O.InvoiceId == InvoiceId
orderby O.OrderNumberId
let AccCharge = (from odec in _uow.OrderDriverExtraCharge.GetAll()
                 where odec.OrderNumber == O.OrderNumber
                 select odec.AccessorialChargeAmount
                ).Sum() ?? 0
let Taxable = (from ac in _uow.AccessorialCharge.GetAll()
               join odec in _uow.OrderDriverExtraCharge.GetAll() on ac.AccessorialChargeId equals odec.AccessorialChargeId
               where ac.Taxable == 1 &&//possibly this you use boolean
                     odec.OrderNumberId == O.OrderNumberId
              ).Sum() ?? 0
select new{
    O.InvoiceId, 
    O.CustID, 
    O.PickupDate, 
    O.OrderDate, 
    O.OrderNumber, 
    O.ProNumber, 
    O.PO1, 
    O.PO2,
    O.BaseRATE,
    O.OrderTotal,
    O.DiscAmount,
    O.NormalDiscount,
    AccCharge,
    Taxable 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var qry = (from O in _uow.Orders.GetAll()
join OD in _uow.OrderDriverExtraCharge.GetAll() on O.OrderNumberId equals OD.OrderNumberId
let AC in _uow.AccessorialCharges.GetAll() on OD.AccessorialChargeId equals AC.AccessorialChargeId
where O.InvoiceId == InvoiceId
select new {

}).Sum(r => (decimal?) r.AccessorialCharges)
```

Comment: also change the type of AccessorialCharges as per you data type